# MVC Dropdownlist how to keep saved value when editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownbox

I have a dropdownlist populated from database. When I go to the edit page to change any field the dropdownlist sets it self to the first value populated in the list. My question is how can I keep the selected value when I try to edit some other fields?

This is view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DEPTID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DEPTID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This is controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, string id2, int id3)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        JOB jOB = db.JOBs.Find(id, id2, id3);
        if (jOB == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.DEPTID = new SelectList(db.DEPARTMENTs.ToList(), "DEPTID", "DEPTID");
        return View(jOB);
    }
```

This is model:

```
 public class JOB
    {
            public string DEPTID { get; set; }
```

Comment: what type `m.DEPTID` is?

Comment: I edited my post and added my model. As you can see DEPTID is string.

Comment: Can't understand you pass `JOB` model to view or `DEPARTMENT`?

Comment: Oh my bad, DEPTID is coming from the JOB model

Comment: Just check that you fill this property according to selected value in selectlist

Comment: So as I understand it should be done here right? ViewBag.DEPTID = new SelectList(db.DEPARTMENTs.ToList(), "DEPTID", "DEPTID"); Can you please give an example?  I am not sure how to check that..

Comment: No i gess it's in your find method, check that you fill property

Comment: Isn't find a system method in System.Data.Entity? I feel like it should be done in the controller

Comment: you always can just check in debug what value contains DEPTID after Find

Comment: I do understand your point but I really don't know how/where to code to set it to its saved value :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot give the `ViewBag` property the same name as the model property your binding to.

In the GET method change the name to (say)

```
ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(db.DEPARTMENTs, "DEPTID", "DEPTID");
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DEPTID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If the value of `DEPTID`matches one of the option values, then that option will be selected when the view is rendered.

Comment: This is it! It worked! It was way simpler than I thought! Thank you so much!

Comment: If I want to edit the record and update it on the same page, your solution is not working.